# Can't add resources to cnvrg CORE

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Good afternoon,

I have recently deployed cnvrg CORE application on-premise with Minikube.

In cnvrg CORE we can create a "machine resource" to give to the application some computer resources like CPU and GPU from a different machine through SSH.

I have found a problem when creating a new resource of any type (in the attached image you can see an example). It says that I can't create the machine because "I have reached the limit" but the only machine I have is the default one (Kubernetes in my case).

I haven't found any information about this on the internet, can you please tell me, is it a problem with the version of cnvrg CORE (v3.9.27)? Or is it something I have to configure during the installation?

Thank you very much!

[cnvrg message "You've reached the maximum machines"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmNRL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to the support of cnvrg and adding machines is not allowed as CORE is a free community version the option to add new resources is not supported. Other paid versions of cnvrg allow you to add new resources and other functionalities, so cnvrg CORE is not a real open-source version of cnvrg.